# Joomla add &quote on my html code

Tags: html, joomla

This is my first time using Joomla. I'm editing a website and if I change the code in the module and save it, Joomla adds \" to all attributes.

This is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<h1 id="consumers">Per chi compra</h1> 
<div class="row-fluid"> 
<div class="span3 gk-demo-content"><img src="templates/meet_gavern/images/content/icon_tick.png" alt="Affidabile, come PayPal" title="TrustBack.me è affidabile" width="109" height="109" /> 
<h2>Affidabile. Come PayPal.</h2> 
<p>Misuriamo l'affidabilità del commercio elettronico. E quando è vero, ci permettiamo anche di dire che un merchant non è affidabile.</p> 
</div>
```

This is the code edited by Joomla :D

```
<div class="\&quot;container-fluid\&quot;">
<h1 id="\&quot;consumers\&quot;">Per chi compra</h1>
<div class="\&quot;row-fluid\&quot;">
<div class="\&quot;span3"><img src="\&quot;templates/meet_gavern/images/content/icon_tick.png\&quot;" alt="\&quot;Affidabile," title="\&quot;TrustBack.me" width="\&quot;109\&quot;" height="\&quot;109\&quot;" />
<h2>Affidabile. Come PayPal.</h2>
<p>Misuriamo l\'affidabilità del commercio elettronico. E quando è vero, ci permettiamo anche di dire che un merchant non è affidabile.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Joomla and which module are you using?

Comment: joomla 3.0 and im using a personal html module

Answer (score 4):

Check your php.ini to see if you have Magic Quotes disabled. If you don't have access to this file, check in the Joomla backend, by going to: `[System] -> [System Information] -> [PHP Setting]`

If it's set to **"on"**, ask your host if they can turn it off for you.

Also, again in the Joomla backend, go to: `[System] -> [Global Configuration] -> [Text Filter Settings]` and ensure it is set to **"No Filtering"** for Super Users.

Please also ensure you are running the latest version of the Joomla 3.0 series (3.0.3).

Comment: It's definitely Magic Quotes.